# improper alphabetic constant with glossaries

Tags: errors, pdftex, glossaries

I've come through an issue while using the glossaries package which returns the "improper alphabetic constant" error when trying to add an entry like

```
 \newglossaryentry{CSV} {
     name={\emph{comma separated values}}, 
     description={Formato eletrónico de armazenamento de dados, sendo cada campo separado por um carater (tabulação ou vírgula)
}
}
```

The error disappears when the backslash is not the first character in the name field, as in

```
 \newglossaryentry{CSV} {
     name={FOO \emph{comma separated values}}, 
     description={Formato eletrónico de armazenamento de dados, sendo cada campo separado por um carater (tabulação ou vírgula)
}
}
```

I am using TeXlive+TeXstudio, being the software and packages up to date, compiling using PDFLaTeX.

So, it allows me to input italics on the name but not from the beginning.
Anyone else having this issue or with any ideas on how to work it out?

Comment: I can't confirm this issue. The first version works out of the box

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{CSV}{
     name={\emph{comma separated values}},
     description={Formato eletrónico de armazenamento de dados,
sendo cada campo separado por um carater (tabulação ou vírgula)}}

\begin{document}

\gls{CSV}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Without a MWE that demonstrates the problem, it's hard to guess what's causing it.

However, if you're doing this with all your entries, it's better to redefine the formatting commands used when displaying the entries. The text produced by commands like `\gls` is enclosed inside `\glstextformat` so to make all your entries use `\emph` within the main part of the document, you can just do:

```
\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

The name in the glossary is placed inside the argument of `\glsnamefont`, so if you want all the entries to have their name emphasized in the glossary, you can just do:

```
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

This keeps all the formatting commands out of the glossary definitions, and makes the document more consistent.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\newglossaryentry{CSV}{
     name={comma separated values},
     description={Formato eletrónico de armazenamento de dados,
sendo cada campo separado por um carater (tabulação ou vírgula)}}

\begin{document}

\gls{CSV}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem is by adding the field "sort":

```
\newglossaryentry{CSV} {
     name={\emph{comma separated values}},
     sort={comma separated values},
     description={Formato eletrónico de armazenamento de dados, sendo cada campo separado por um carater (tabulação ou vírgula)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The entry in `name` should be a string with no formatting instructions; for printing in text with some formatting, use `text`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{CSV}{
  name={comma separated values},
  text={\emph{comma separated values}},
  description={%
    Formato eletrónico de armazenamento de dados, sendo cada campo
    separado por um carater (tabulação ou vírgula)%
  }
}

\begin{document}

Text \gls{CSV}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]